# Optimising pagination with large dataset and offset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose that I have 50 million record of user.
And the business requirement is to allow the admin to select any pageNumber and any pageSize to retrieve the user record

Of course, it will not be a problem if admin key in page 1 with pageSize of 10.
But let say admin key in page 1 million with pageSize of 10, the querying time is a problem.

Is there any solution to this as a simple offset and limit solution with indexing alone wouldn't solve the problem??? I am thinking that how could this be addressed without changing the business requirement.

**Simplify:** 
- I need a stored proc that accept pageSize and pageNumber to get user record 
- I have 50 million user record 
- The user id in my database is guid (not incremental based on created date)
 
- Query result should be order by User Created datetime 
- ***Expectation: Querying time of pageNumber 1 and pageNumber 1 million should not be much different, or at the very least it should be acceptable time to return result (eg: less than 5 seconds)***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AdminGetUserList] (
     @PageSize int = 10,
     @PageNumber int = 1
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        *
    FROM [dbo].[User]
    ORDER BY [JoinDT]
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);

END
```

**Note:**

I know that there is solution which use the last primary key (incremental userid) in this case instead of using offset, but such solution would not fit the business requirement as business requirement allow user to key in pageNumber(offset). In other word, solution like this will not work for my case.

```
SELECT user_id, name
FROM users
WHERE user_id > 51 234 123
ORDER BY user_id ASC
LIMIT 10 000;
```

Comment: @RandiVertongen PageSize means limit, which is the amount of rows. By PageNumber i mean offset. So with a pageSize of 10, and pageNumber of 1 million, i would retrieve record from 10million + 1 to 10 million + 10. And no, it wouldn't be order by user_id ASC (as mention, the code example above does not fit the business requirement). First of all, user_id in my case is not incremental. It should be order by user created dt.

Comment: @RandiVertongen u can refer to my updated question.

Comment: Great, so you have the procedure you are using but want it to be optimized correct?

Comment: @RandiVertongen Yes, i want to optimise the stored procedure such that the when i key in PageNumber = 1 milllion the query return time is similar to PageNumber = 1. Is this something possible to be done?

Comment: As a side note, an interesting read on optimizing offset fetch can be found [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)

Comment: @RandiVertongen have read that previously, it still does not address and solve the problem that the querying time is getting longer with higher offset.

Comment: Did you try the CTE approach, where the CTE finds the offset using a much narrower select than the `SELECT *` in your question? The `SELECT *` version will almost certainly have to use a clustered index scan (unless you have a covering index) and, unless the whole table is in memory, I expect it to take way longer to hit page 1 million than page 1. Show *that* query, the index supporting it, and the actual plan for page 1 vs. 1 million. That will be much more productive than just hand-waving it away as "not addressing the problem." It certainly can help, but you have to apply it correctly.

Comment: Offset based pagination will be progressively slower as the offset increases, even after optimization. I can't see a business case where a query that skips to page 1M of a 50M row table is useful. FWIW, it takes about 5 seconds to skip to page 1M on my PC against a clustered columnstore indexed table selecting all 8 columns.

Comment: This is a great article describing the approach Aaron is talking about. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/optimising-server-side-paging-part-i